# Google map Error

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I got error when using the Google map

- You have Included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
  This may cause unexpected errors.
- Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired
- Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys but I have a API keys

**This is my footer tag**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js">
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your API key is missing

It looks like you have not included the key in your Google maps script request.

Google has an [official guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) for how to set up everything

The take away in your case is that you included the script like so:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=">
</script>
```

You're missing the key parameter in the url. This is how google wants your request

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Notice the part where it says `key=YOUR_API_KEY` That's where you need to put your API key.

The API key looks like this: (not an actual key)

```
AIzaSyBMh448pWbvhyvsqY4OasYmam4ppD2CHPM
```

Your final link should look like this:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBMh448pWbvhyvsqY4OasYmam4ppD2CHPM"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### More than one request

The other warning:

*"You have Included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page"*

indicates that your have tried to request Google maps API more than once on the same page. I don't see that in your example code. You may have another request someplace else like in the `header`. **Don't use more than one per page.**

**Edit:**

After looking at your page source I found this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

This is the extra request that's causing the error where the API is requested multiple times.

Comment: Ok, just add `<script async defer src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyALFmgk735W8ZyKpVVJF0of9FNSzTyt80A&call‌​back=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>` instead of you have in the footer to see if that works

Comment: Try to find where the other request is.

Comment: Still error, another error found 'initMap is not a function'.

Comment: You can ignore the new error that came up that just occurs because of the load order. The new error won't show up if you use `<script async defer src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyALFmgk‌​735W8ZyKpVVJF0of9FNS‌​zTyt80A" type="text/javascript"></script>` I still think your main problem is multiple API requests. Is your site live?

Comment: I see ... okey okey !

Comment: **Right click** somewhere **empty** on the page and click on **view page source** Then use **ctrl+f** and search for `maps.googleapis` That will give you an idea where the requests are located in your document.

Comment: I found it but I which this one is !

Comment: That's not what I expected. Copy your entire *page source* and paste it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/) then click *save* then copy the url and put it here so I can have a look and try to see if there's something else wrong.

Comment: Try to remove these two scripts from your code **temporarily**: `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase.js"></script>` and also 

`<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js">
</script>` I think [firebase.js](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/firebase) might be the issue

Comment: Done but still I will send another view source

Comment: Ok, There two more things we can try. First, put the firebase.js links back.

Comment: Then, find `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>` and **temporarily** remove it. it's right below your `</nav>` tag

Comment: @Leira No problem. Happy to help. Thank you.